# After running CDE I can't build sample polymer app in dart editor

Tags: dart, dart-pub

```
file:/C:/Users/Dave/dart/td2/build.dart
build.dart returned error code 255

Unhandled exception:
Uncaught Error: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\Dave\dart\td2\packages\args\args.dart' (OS Error: The system cannot find the file specified., errno = 2)
Stack Trace:
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:349)
#1      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1151)
```

Dart editor was working fine with a polymer app that I was developing previously.
I have rebooted, reinstalled dart editor with no luck
Running Pub Get manually fails as well as it can't find files either.  Evrrything was working prior to trying CDE and the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I think running `pub cache repair` (run in command line interface) should be able to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, that helped I can now run the demo (CkickCounter) but the repair gets part way through and then starts to complain and says that the error is likely temporary and to try again.  When I try again it says that it can't find pubspec.yaml.  It there any way that I can just delete the cache?

Comment: There is an open issue that makes `pub cache repair` fail when the `pubspec.yaml` is missing. On Linux systems you can just delete `~/.pub-cache`. I don't know the path on other OS. You should be able to find out by following the symlinks in the packages directory.

Comment: Gunter, Thanks for your help.  I deleted C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org  where Dave is my username on Windows 8.1 and everything seems fine now.  Thanks

Comment: See also comments to https://plus.google.com/113415344870093527255/posts/Tab8xQnqoFs