# Threading in Dart : Could not import Package

Tags: multithreading, dart

**Machine: Linux (Ubuntu 17.04)**

Trying to execute this program:
[example/example_interleaved_execution.dart](https://github.com/mezoni/threading/blob/master/example/example_interleaved_execution.dart)

```
$ dart example_interleaved_execution.dart
```

**Error:**

```
Unhandled exception:
Could not import "package:threading/threading.dart" from "file:///home/xxxxs/devel/dartprog/example_interleaved_execution.dart": Could not resolve a package location for base at file:///home/xxxxs/devel/dartprog/example_interleaved_execution.dart
null:
```

**Already Tried:**

- `pub cache repair` [Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842778/dart-import-packages-not-working)
- Deleted `~/.pub-cache`
- Rebooted machine and tried  `$ dart example_interleaved_execution.dart` and same error.

How to solve this one?

(**Note:** If anyone is working behind proxy, make sure "pub" is working under root too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to generate a `pubspec.yaml` file yourself with a config somewhat like this:

```yaml
name: my_test_lib

dependencies:
  threading: ^0.0.8
```

Then you can do a `pub get` which will install the needed dependency.